# Selenium-IDE: How to simulate non-printable keys (ENTER, ESC, Backspace)?

Tags: keyboard, keypress, selenium-ide, enter, backspace

What is the exact HTML code to simulate ENTER, ESC, BACKSPACE and DOWN in Selenium IDE 1.3.0?

`typeKeys` didn't work nor did this:

```
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=zc_0_4_3-real</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyUp</td>
    <td>id=zc_0_4_3-real</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyPress</td>
    <td>id=zc_0_4_3-real</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For example to submit a form by pressing enter, the only one I can figure out is:

```
Command: keyPressAndWait
Target:  id=q              [depends on your form of course]
Value:   \\13              [for enter - any ascii value can go here]
```

So it looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td>keyPressAndWait</td>
<td>id=q</td>
<td>\13</td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps
Paul

**Update:**

`keyPressAndWait` is deprecated

Now you can use:

Command: `sendKeys`,

Target: `id=<your id>`,

Value: `<your letter in utf8 and not ascii anymore>`

For non-printable keys you can have a look at this page:
http://www.testingdiaries.com/selenium-ide-keypress-events/

Comment: For anyone else encountering the \\13 problem. Ensure you are using the correct command, eg keyPress, and not typeKeys.

Comment: Right, don't use `sendKeys`. Use `keyPress`

Answer (score 18):

None of the solutions above helped me, however, the special keys described here this did the trick:

http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-1/

```
sendKeys | id=search | ${KEY_ENTER}
```

Special keys - like normal keys, only a bit special. :)

Comment: add content in ur answer

Answer (score 10):

you can use ${KEY_ENTER} and for other keys as the same as ${KEY_F8},${KEY_ESC}.. etc

[Here is a blog post with more details](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-2/).

Comment: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: dont know, but i have used in my testing today. if needed use in your testing

Comment: @AaronDigulla thanks that was the perfect dot com where i searched for.

Comment: It's documented Here! And thank you for that Emmanuel Angelo R.

Answer (score 8):

For the newer versions of Firefox (22 & 23) the typeKeys command won't work in the Selenium IDE. It's deprecated. You have to use sendKeys.

```
command = sendKeys 
target = css=.someclass 
value = ${KEY_ENTER}
```

If you want to combine text with special keys you can do something like:

```
command = sendKeys 
target = css=.someclass 
value = demo${KEY_ENTER}
```

Answer (score 3):

These methods doesn't work with the *TAB* key.

To simulate the TAB key pressed we need to use the command **fireEvent** like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clear text field using Ctrl+A and Del (for Selenium IDE):

```
<tr>
<td>keyDown</td>
<td>id=your text field id</td>
<td>\17</td>
```

```
<tr>
<td>keyPress</td>
<td>id=your text field id</td>
<td>\65</td>
```

```
<tr>
<td>keyUp</td>
<td>id=your text field id</td>
<td>\17</td>
```

```
<tr>
<td>keyPress</td>
<td>id=your text field id</td>
<td>\127</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code 13 for enter key, code 9 for tab key, code 40 for down key, 8 for backspace key

Answer (score 0):

The Best Answer to the qs how to Record the Enter Key Through Selenium IDE

```
<tr>
<td>keyDown</td>
<td>id=txtFilterContentUnit</td>
<td>\13 </td>
</tr>
```

Its Working i tried that on Selenium IDE here. replace `txtFilterContentUnit` with your text box name.

hope u can do it -Abhijeet

Comment: This is not recording anything, this is manual typing you have to do yourself, right?